# Pymodbus server - catch value and address of written register

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus

I want to use pymodbus server as a convertor between an api and modbus. I have succesfully set a modbus server and im updating holding register values from an api device. Now i need to write values to this api but i need to detect when a modbus client writes values to my modbus server. It will be enough if someone show me how to print written address of register and value to a console. Im using this code for creating the server: https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/example/updating_server.html

Thank you.